# Stringify structure in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, encode

I want to be able to output a stringifid version of a structure in Matlab. I already found http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15017-struct2str but this outputs `boolVariable: [1x1 logical]` for logical variables.

The builtin disp function displays logical variables with a one or zero but cuts off strings, e.g. `test: [1x103 char]`.

How can I both output a full string and a readable boolean representation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe JSON works for you.
There's no builtin solution for that, but google e.g. yields this package:

http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~kyamagu/software/json/

It should serialize strings fully and make logicals either 0/1 or true/false, the website doesn 't tell and I didn't test it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Nonetheless, is there still a way to let matlab display the full string instead of doing something like this: test: [1x103 char]?

Comment: Check the `format` command in the docs. `format long` seems to do the trick.

Comment: `format long` only specifies the accuracy of numerical values. Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything in the docs concerning the format of char arrays.